ActiveMQ Classic with Spring Boot microservice-based application, reconnection issue
I'm working on a Spring Boot microservice-based backend application with ActiveMQ Classic to communicate between them. I had a problem in our production environment where, by maintenance, the ActiveMQ Classic Kubernetes instance was restarted. All microservices reconnected once the it was up and ready again, except for one: it kept trying to reconnect without success.
After 160+ retries in my local environment, I've been able to reproduce the issue just once and without more error traces than the microservice logs:
Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination '<queueName>' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=128, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: The JMS connection has failed: java.io.EOFException

As you can see this is a very rare error but it happens. In terms of configurations, everything looks alright, it tries to reconnect every 5 seconds forever (it usually works instantly). With Amazon MQ I did not find any extra config parameter available related to my issue.
My only guess is that maybe two microservices tried to reconnect at the exact same time and one override the connection of the other. Can this even happen? Any other possibilities?
jakarta.jms.JMSException: java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:67) ~[activemq-client-jakarta-5.18.3.jar:5.18.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.onAsyncException(ActiveMQConnection.java:2033) ~[activemq-client-jakarta-5.18.3.jar:5.18.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.onException(ActiveMQConnection.java:2052) ~[activemq-client-jakarta-5.18.3.jar:5.18.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.onException(TransportFilter.java:114) ~[activemq-client-jakarta-5.18.3.jar:5.18.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.onException(ResponseCorrelator.java:126) ~[activemq-client-jakarta-5.18.3.jar:5.18.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.onException(TransportFilter.java:114) ~[activemq-client-jakarta-5.18.3.jar:5.18.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.onException(TransportFilter.java:114) ~[activemq-client-jakarta-5.18.3.jar:5.18.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.onException(WireFormatNegotiator.java:173) ~[activemq-client-jakarta-5.18.3.jar:5.18.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.onException(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:346) ~[activemq-client-jakarta-5.18.3.jar:5.18.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportSupport.onException(TransportSupport.java:96) ~[activemq-client-jakarta-5.18.3.jar:5.18.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:219) ~[activemq-client-jakarta-5.18.3.jar:5.18.3]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: null
    at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:398) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.activemq.openwire.OpenWireFormat.unmarshal(OpenWireFormat.java:280) ~[activemq-client-jakarta-5.18.3.jar:5.18.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.readCommand(TcpTransport.java:240) ~[activemq-client-jakarta-5.18.3.jar:5.18.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:232) ~[activemq-client-jakarta-5.18.3.jar:5.18.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:215) ~[activemq-client-jakarta-5.18.3.jar:5.18.3]
    ... 1 common frames omitted


ActiveMQ Classic is designed to handle concurrent connection attempts so your suspicion is almost certainly not what's happening. Do you have the stack-trace for the java.io.EOFException? That would help explain what's happening. Without additional details there's really no way to say what's actually happening here.

What version of ActiveMQ Classic are you using?

In local I'm using rmohr/activemq:5.15.9-alpine, at AWS I have Apache ActiveMQ 5.17.6.
No more errors are shown apart from the one in the post. Complete error is:
2024-05-30T08:29:42.965+02:00 ERROR 24104 --- [ntContainer#6-1] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'topic/topic' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=3, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://127.0.0.1:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information

Also edited the post, I added another error I have when I disconnect manually the activeMQ in local.
